# Graph Not form Correctly

Tags: c#, mschart

[image: This Graph create when user select his setting first time and save it][image: This graph form by user save setting]I am working on Asp.Net Chart using C# language.I give option to user that he select fields from database and form a graph also have a option to save these settings with name and make a smart list when user want to see his save setting he just click and graph formd .But when user click on the name of his save setting graph not form correctly and also not showing the axis correctly my code is as follows:

```
protected void btnShowSmartList_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        string _SmartList ;
        ds = GetDataSet("SELECT [Sql_Query] FROM [DWH_SmartList] WHERE sys_SmartList_No=" + ddSmartQueryList.SelectedValue)   ;
        _SmartList = Convert.ToString(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Sql_Query"]);

        ds.Tables[0].Dispose();
        ds = new DataSet();
        ds = GetDataSet(_SmartList);
        Chart1.DataSource = ds;
        Chart1.Legends.Add("Inspection_Date").Title = "Inspection_Date";
        Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.Title = Dd_List.SelectedValue;
        Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
        Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.MajorTickMark.Enabled = false;
        Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.MajorTickMark.Enabled = false;
        Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
        Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.MinorGrid.Enabled = false;
        Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.MinorTickMark.Enabled = false;
        Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.MinorGrid.Enabled = false;
        Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.MinorTickMark.Enabled = false;
        Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.Title = Dd_ListY.SelectedValue;
        Chart1.Series["Series1"].XValueMember = Dd_List.SelectedValue;
        Chart1.Series["Series1"].YValueMembers = Dd_ListY.SelectedValue;
        Chart1.Series["Series1"].LegendText = Dd_ListY.SelectedValue;

        this.GridFormatting();
        Chart1.DataBind();
        //Chart1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
        // this.Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.IsStartedFromZero = false;

        GridView1.SelectedIndex = 0;
        GridView1.DataSource = ds;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

Grid working great but graph not

Comment: You mean the graph is not showing / not showing correctly? please describe more, preferably with screenshot & sample data.

Comment: @ShivanRaptor i upload graph image

Comment: I point out the problem in my program but i dont know how to solve it SQL_Query is the field of Database where my Query has been saved when use want to save it in SmartList and giving it any name XYZ when he again want to open it he click on it and graph formed but in Chart codding i define value from DropdownList name Dd_ListY.SelectedValue but Query Save the actual value so how can i make graph from the query which was save in DB in SQL_Query Column .it shows data correctly in the gridview.But not in the Chart because Chart control not found the value of Dd_ListY.Selectedvlaue.Any solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this problem myself first i saved the value in database of all my Axis with this code

{

```
    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["KTConnectionString"].ToString();
    cmd.Connection = con;
    KTDataContext dataContext = new KTDataContext(connectionString);
    DWH_SmartList tbip = new DWH_SmartList();
    tbip.Sql_Query = txtQuery.Text;
    tbip.Y_Axis = Dd_ListY.SelectedValue;
    tbip.Y1_Axis = Dd_ListYSec.SelectedValue;
    tbip.Y2_Axis = Dd_List3.SelectedValue;
    tbip.Y3_Axis = Dd_List4.SelectedValue;
    tbip.Y4_Axis = Dd_List5.SelectedValue;
    tbip.SmartList_Description = txt_SmartList.Text;
    tbip.User_Code = Convert.ToInt32(  Session["UserCode"]); 
    dataContext.DWH_SmartLists.InsertOnSubmit(tbip);
    dataContext.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Then i retrieve it by this code:
{

```
    string _SmartList,_yaxis,_y1axis,_y2axis,_y3axis,_y4axis,_y5axis;
    ds = GetDataSet("SELECT [Sql_Query],[Y_Axis],[Y1_Axis],[Y2_Axis],[Y3_Axis],[Y4_Axis],[Y5_Axis] FROM [DWH_SmartList] WHERE sys_SmartList_No=" + ddSmartQueryList.SelectedValue)   ;
    _SmartList = Convert.ToString(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Sql_Query"]);

    _yaxis = Convert.ToString(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Y_Axis"]);
    _y1axis= Convert.ToString(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Y1_Axis"]);
    _y2axis = Convert.ToString(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Y2_Axis"]);
    _y3axis = Convert.ToString(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Y4_Axis"]);
    _y4axis = Convert.ToString(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Y4_Axis"]);
    _y5axis = Convert.ToString(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Y5_Axis"]);
    Dd_ListY.SelectedValue = _yaxis ;
    Dd_ListYSec.SelectedValue = _y1axis;
    Dd_List3.SelectedValue = _y2axis;
    Dd_List4.SelectedValue = _y3axis;
    Dd_List5.SelectedValue = _y4axis;
    ds.Tables[0].Dispose();
    ds = new DataSet();
    ds = GetDataSet(_SmartList);
    Chart1.DataSource = ds;
    Chart1.Legends.Add("Inspection_Date").Title = "Inspection_Date";
    Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.Title = Dd_List.SelectedValue;
    Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
    Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.MajorTickMark.Enabled = false;
    Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.MajorTickMark.Enabled = false;
    Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
    Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.MinorGrid.Enabled = false;
    Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.MinorTickMark.Enabled = false;
    Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.MinorGrid.Enabled = false;
    Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.MinorTickMark.Enabled = false;
    Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.Title = Dd_ListY.SelectedValue;
    Chart1.Series["Series1"].XValueMember = Dd_List.SelectedValue;
    Chart1.Series["Series1"].YValueMembers = Dd_ListY.SelectedValue;
    Chart1.Series["Series1"].LegendText = Dd_ListY.SelectedValue;



    this.GridFormatting();
    Chart1.DataBind();
    //Chart1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
    // this.Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.IsStartedFromZero = false;




    GridView1.SelectedIndex = 0;
    GridView1.DataSource = ds;
    GridView1.DataBind();

}
```

and my project also completed thenk for support and help me stackoverflow professionals and http://stackoverflow.com